# Automapper with ninject and generic interface won't work (error activating/no matching bindings available)

Tags: c#, generics, ninject, automapper

I'm trying to use automapper in combination with ninject and a generic interface, abstract class. However it doesn't seem to work.

Below you will find the code which I'm trying to use. What am I missing?

**IMapper**

```
 public interface IMapper<in TTypeFrom, TTypeTo>
{
    TTypeTo Map(TTypeFrom typeFrom);
    List<TTypeTo> Map(IEnumerable<TTypeFrom> itemToMap);
}
public abstract class Mapper<TTypeFrom, TTypeto> : IMapper<TTypeFrom, TTypeto>
{
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mappingEngine;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    protected Mapper(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
        _configuration = configuration;

        _configuration.CreateMap<TTypeFrom, TTypeto>();
    }

    public TTypeto Map(TTypeFrom typeFrom)
    {
        return Map<TTypeFrom, TTypeto>(typeFrom);
    }
    protected TTo Map<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom itemToMap)
    {
        return _mappingEngine.Map<TFrom, TTo>(itemToMap);
    }

    public List<TTypeto> Map(IEnumerable<TTypeFrom> itemToMap)
    {
        return Map<TTypeFrom, TTypeto>(itemToMap);
    }
    protected List<TTo> Map<TFrom, TTo>(IEnumerable<TFrom> itemsToMap)
    {
        return itemsToMap.Select(Map<TFrom, TTo>).ToList();
    }
}
```

**CategoryRepresentationMapper**

```
public interface ICategoryRepresentationMapper : IMapper<CategoryRepresentation, CategoryRepresentationDto>
{

}
public class CategoryRepresentationMapper : Mapper<CategoryRepresentation, CategoryRepresentationDto>, ICategoryRepresentationMapper
{
    public CategoryRepresentationMapper(IMappingEngine mappingEngine, IConfiguration configuration) : base(mappingEngine, configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

**Setting things up with ninject**

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();


        Mapper.Initialize(map =>
        {
            map.ConstructServicesUsing(f => kernel.Get(f));
        });

        kernel.Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Engine);
        kernel.Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider);
        kernel.Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Configuration);

        kernel.Bind(
          x =>
              x.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(IMapper<,>))
                  .SelectAllClasses()
                  .InheritedFrom(typeof(IMapper<,>))
                  .BindAllInterfaces());

        var categoryRepresentationMapper = kernel.Get<ICategoryRepresentationMapper>();
```

I get the following error:

```
 Ninject.ActivationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error activating ICategoryRepresentationMapper
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  1) Request for ICategoryRepresentationMapper

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for ICategoryRepresentationMapper.
  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
  4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
  5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

**Edit**

If i do this, it will work, BUT I don't want to bind ICategoryRepresentationMapper explicitly. It must be generic since I will have numerous mappers.

```
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();


            Mapper.Initialize(map =>
            {
                map.ConstructServicesUsing(f => kernel.Get(f));
            });

            kernel.Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Engine);
            kernel.Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider);
            kernel.Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Configuration);     
// This line below will actualy work but it isn't generic                 
            kernel.Bind(
              x =>
                  x.FromAssemblyContaining< ICategoryRepresentationMapper>()
                      .SelectAllClasses()
                      .InheritedFrom(typeof(IMapper<,>))
                      .BindAllInterfaces());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found an answer to this problem. The assemblies were to look at where wrong.

Instead of doing this:

```
kernel.Bind(
      x =>
          x.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(IMapper<,>))
              .SelectAllClasses()
              .InheritedFrom(typeof(IMapper<,>))
              .BindAllInterfaces());
```

I needed to do this and It works:

```
var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        var uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);

        _kernel.Bind(
          x =>
              x.FromAssembliesInPath(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
                  .SelectAllClasses()
                  .InheritedFrom(typeof(IMapper<,>))
                  .BindAllInterfaces());
```